# On configuration changed layout not changed automatically in android

Tags: android

i am using a `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in android **manifest** due to which when i rotate my device,my device don't pick the layout XML file in layout-land folder can any one tell me what is the problem?

Comment: i am using a android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in android manifest -- That's your problem. Stop using that.

Comment: use the same name XML file in portrait and landscape layout.

Comment: no its must i cant stop using it

Comment: iam doing same thing but due to configurationChanges android not picking the layout-land folder xml file

Comment: how your create a layout folder.are you set to changed the landscape mode while creating the folder?

Comment: i have created a layout-land folder inside it i kept the same xml file but with different margins of a textfiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to use android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" then you have manually update the layouts when the screen rotates.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.portrait);
    }
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.landscape);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Using fragments complicates things and using android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" its not recommended anyway. You should use onSaveInstanceState in the fragment to save the fragment's state and then restore the fragment state in onCreateView:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment
{
    private EditText ed;

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index)
    {
        return new DetailsFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        ed = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_edit);

        if(null != savedInstanceState)
        {
            //restore the text if null != savedInstanceState -> fragment is recreated
            ed.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("RESTORE_TEXT"));
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        if(null != ed)
        {
            //save the text written in the edittext
            outState.putString("RESTORE_TEXT", ed.getText().toString());
        }

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

I've written the above example in a project that you can find [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7w9sboxs5ishdo/fragmenttest.zip) and you can see better how it works. Hope it helps.

Comment: but in fragment there is no method setContentView

Comment: I don't see nowhere in your question that you mention you are using fragments.

Comment: sorry my mistake but iam using a fragment in that case what i do